# Siunitx's \micro symbol has serif

Tags: fonts, siunitx

I am trying to reproduce the look of the micro symbol in the `siunitx`
documentation; see for instance the following picture:

[image: \micro from documentation]

However, when compiling the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}  

\begin{document}

\SI{15}{\micro\metre}

\end{document}
```

the mu comes out with serif as in the following picture:

[image: mu from my code]

I suppose there is a font issue here but I could find how to solve it by reading the `siunitx` documentation.

Comment: You can adjust the definition, but why do you expect there to be no serif here?

Comment: Different font, try replacing `lmodern` with `mathpazo`.

Comment: Admitedly serif in a serif text is rather normal. However some people find that the serif on the mu look odd and also (mainly) the mu in the documentation are sans-serif even in serif text.
I was wondering how you achieved that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, you're using a font different to that of the manual. Replace `lmodern` with `mathpazo` to get the same font. (This will of course influence the entire document.)

Answer (score 11):

Finding the 'correct' micro symbol is tricky as a lot of fonts do not include the appropriate (upright, roman font, 'matching') micro or mu. The `siunitx` package therefore provides two options which control the symbol used here: `math-micro` and `text-micro`. These are used to set the symbol in math and text mode, respectively. Simply pick a formulation you like and use `\sisetup` to activate it

```
\sisetup{math-micro = <your-choice-here>, text-micro = <your-choice-here>}
```

Comment: A concrete example that works nicely if using `arev`, is to use Helvetica for `\micro`: `\sisetup{math-micro={\usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\text{\textmu}}}`.